# how to create wireframe structure for modelling a Tree

Tags: wireframe

I cannot figure out how to extrude a single vertex so as to create a wireframe structure as shown 35secs into the video.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cgiJHxaTank&t=57s

I believe there is an option with a "Single Vert" function somewhere?

Comment: Add a simple vert in a mesh object (in Edit mode) and extrude it where you want by press "E". You can also connect two vert by select them and press "F". He used the Skin and the Subdivision Surface modifiers which does exactly what you saw.

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**What he's doing in the video is extruding <kbd>E</kbd> a single vertex. You have 2 main ways to do that:**

**1**- Simply add a plane, go into edit mode <kbd>Tab</kbd>, select 3 vertices and delete them by pressing <kbd>X</kbd> and then selecting vertices. After that, go back to object mode <kbd>Tab</kbd> and on the top left corner click "Object" than "Set Origin" and "Geometry to Origin". Now if you go once again back to edit mode <kbd>Tab</kbd>, you will have a single vertex that you can extrude by pressing <kbd>E</kbd>.

**2**- The other and easier way to do it is: Go to the top left corner, click "Edit", than "Preferences" and go to "Add-ons". Search for "Add Mesh: Extra Objects" and enable it. Now go back to the viewport and press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, under "Mesh" you will find "Single Vert", click that and select "Add Single Vert", what that will do is add a single vertex that you can extrude by pressing <kbd>E</kbd> on edit mode.

**Both ways will give you the effect you see on the video, but I recommend using the second one as it's easier and will save you a lot of time in the future.**

Comment: A quicker way to do your first option .. 1. Create a plane 2. **M** > 'Merge at Center'